# Data Modelling which option is good?

Tags: firebase

I have one confusion , while modelling our data in the firebase / nosql which option is good.Which to go for in what condition?

```
roles: 
  -RJSmxksixk233s
      roleName : 'admin'
```

Now to refer it in another collection we have 2 options.

Option 1 :   "roleid": '-RJSmxksixk233s'

Option 2 :   "-RJSmxksixk233s": true

```
users: 
  -RsJSmxksixk233s
      "roleid": '-RJSmxksixk233s',
      'roleName' : 'admin'
```

or

```
users: 
   -RsJSmxksixk233s
      '-RJSmxksixk233s':true,
      roleName: 'admin'
```

both can be used to denote to refer roles.

Now the confusion is when to use which ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is no perfect way of modeling a Firebase database. You need to model your database according to your needs. As i see in your examples, IMHO i cannot say that an example is better then the other without knowing what you need to achieve. The important thing to note is, if you want to query your database for the id, then use:

```
"roleid": '-RJSmxksixk233s'
```

If you want to query your database only for the existens of that id, then use:

```
'-RJSmxksixk233s':true
```

Hope it helps.